# How to properly eliminate elements in dictionary until one string remains

Tags: python, dictionary

I really need help on this

```
def get_winner (dict_winner):
    new_dict = {} 
    for winner in dict_winner:
        first_letter = winner[0]
        value = dict_winner[winner]
        if first_letter in new_dict:
            new_dict[first_letter] += value
        else:
            new_dict[first_letter] = value
    return (new_dict)


get_winner({
    ('C', 'A', 'B', 'D') :3,
    ('D', 'B', 'C', 'A') :2,
    ('C', 'D', 'A', 'B') :1,
    ('A', 'D', 'B', 'C') :2,
    ('A', 'D', 'C', 'B') :4, 
    ('A', 'C', 'D', 'B') :2
})

#Outputs {'A': 8, 'D': 2, 'C': 4}
```

Now I want the result be a tuple of str, NoneType..

Also, it is eliminating only the letter with the smallest value in first place only one time. I want it to repeat this process until I get one winner in the end. So in this case all the B's will be eliminated in the dict itself, not in the output. for example:

```
first time = [8, 0, 4, 2] 
second time = {
    ('C', 'A', 'D') :3, 
    ('D', 'C', 'A') :2,
    ('C', 'D', 'A') :1,
    ('A', 'D', 'C') :2,
    ('A', 'D', 'C') :4,
    ('A', 'C', 'D') :2
}) 
#Outputs C = 4 D = 2 A = 8 

third time= {
    ('C', 'A') :3, 
    ('C', 'A') :2, 
    ('C', 'A') :1, 
    ('A', 'C') :2, 
    ('A', 'C') :4,
    ('A', 'C') :2
}) 
#Outputs C = 6 A = 8
```

8/ 14 > 50%, I know that should have been the case since the beginning because `A` already had the majority value. But i am assuming `A` has a value of 40% which is when elimination should begin. So, could you point out where I went wrong in coding this? In the example `A` should be the winner! So the output shopuld be
('A', None)

Comment: Are you attempting to implement [Condorcet voting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method)?

Comment: Your dicts contains duplicate keys?? `third_time` will be actually passed as `{('A', 'C'): 2, ('C', 'A'): 1}`

Answer (score 0):

Your current code counts the number of times each candidate is the first on the list. It doesn't "eliminate" anyone, it just gives the appearance of doing so since one of your candidates gets no first-place votes.

I suggest doing it recursively. Your base case is "a candidate gets over 50% of the vote". Something like this:

```
def get_winner(vote_dict)
    total_votes = sum(vote_dict.values())
    votes_by_candidate = defaultdict(int)    # This makes your if/else block redundant

    for vote_pattern in vote_dict:
        votes_by_candidate[vote_pattern[0]] += vote_dict[vote_pattern]

    for candidate in votes_by_candidate:
         if votes_by_candidate[candidate] * 2 > total_votes:
             return candidate

    new_dict = defaultdict(int)
    eliminated = min(votes_by_candidate, key=votes_by_candidate.get)

    for vote_pattern in vote_dict:
        new_pattern = [candidate for candidate in vote_pattern if candidate != eliminated]
        new_dict[new_pattern] += vote_dict[vote_pattern]

    return get_winner(new_dict)
```

Comment: Those are not duplicates... because they are basically being edited in the dictionary until the end, when i can finally show the out put

Answer (score 0):

My solution - in one step:

```
def get_winner(candidates):
    winners = dict.fromkeys(map(lambda f: f[0] for f in candidates.keys()))
    for cand, votes in candidates.iteritems(): 
        winners[cand[0]]+=votes
    return [winner for winner, vote in winners.iteritems() if vote ==max(winners.values())]
```

It is not fancy, but it is simple :-)