# How to add values accordingly of the first indices of a dictionary of tuples of a list of strings? Python 3x

Tags: python, key, tuples, dictionary

I'm stuck on how to formulate this problem properly and the following is:

What if we had the following values:

```
{('A','B','C','D'):3, 
('A','C','B','D'):2,
('B','D','C','A'):4,
('D','C','B','A'):3,
('C','B','A','D'):1,
('C','D','A','B'):1}
```

When we sum up the first place values: [5,4,2,3] (5 people picked for A first, 4 people picked for B first, and so on like A = 5, B = 4, C = 2, D = 3)

The maximum values for any alphabet is 5, which isn't a majority (5/14 is less than half), where 14 is the sum of total values.

So we remove the alphabet with the fewest first place picks. Which in this case is C.

I want to return a dictionary where `{'A':5, 'B':4, 'C':2, 'D':3}` **without importing** anything.

This is my work:

```
def popular(letter):
    '''(dict of {tuple of (str, str, str, str): int}) -> dict of {str:int}
    '''
    my_dictionary = {}
    counter = 0

    for (alphabet, picks) in letter.items():
        if (alphabet[0]):
            my_dictionary[alphabet[0]] = picks
        else:
            my_dictionary[alphabet[0]] = counter

    return my_dictionary
```

This returns duplicate of keys which I cannot get rid of.

Thanks.

Comment: One of your classmates is working on [the same homework problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569105/how-to-properly-eliminate-elements-in-dictionary-until-one-string-remains/13569432).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
def popular(letter):
    '''(dict of {tuple of (str, str, str, str): int}) -> dict of {str:int}
    '''
    my_dictionary = {}
    for alphabet, picks in letter.items():
        if alphabet[0] in my_dictionary:
            my_dictionary[alphabet[0]] += picks
        else:
            my_dictionary[alphabet[0]] = picks
    return my_dictionary
```

Example:

```
>>> letter = {('A','B','C','D'):3, 
... ('A','C','B','D'):2,
... ('B','D','C','A'):4,
... ('D','C','B','A'):3,
... ('C','B','A','D'):1,
... ('C','D','A','B'):1}
>>> popular(letter)
{'A': 5, 'C': 2, 'B': 4, 'D': 3}
```

This could be accomplished more concisely using [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def popular(letter):
    my_dictionary = defaultdict(int)
    for alphabet, picks in letter.items():
        my_dictionary[alphabet[0]] += picks
    return dict(my_dictionary)
```