# How to remove duplicate items in multiple tuples of a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I need help on how to remove duplicate items in a tuple of a dictionary.

```
dict of {tuple of (str, str, str, str): int}) -> tuple of (str, None)
```

Here is the dictionary:

```
   {('ALPHA', 'BETA', 'GAMMA', 'DELTA'): 5
    ('BETA', 'GAMMA', 'ALPHA', 'DELTA'): 3
    ('DELTA', 'BETA', 'GAMMA', 'ALPHA'): 1
    ('GAMMA', 'DELTA', 'ALPHA', 'BETA'): 3
    ('BETA', 'ALPHA', 'DELTA', 'GAMMA'): 4}
```

and the integer is the value of the first index of the `tuple` such that I got to group them by:

```
def rad_type(particle):

   my_dict = {}

   for (k, v) in particle.items():
        if (k[0] in my_dict):
            my_dict[k[0]] += v
        else:
            my_dict[k[0]] = v

   return my_dict
```

This returns:

```
{'ALPHA': 5, 'BETA': 7, 'GAMMA': 3, 'DELTA': 1}
```

Since `'DELTA'` has the least value which in this case is 1, but I want to remove the element like this:

```
   {('ALPHA', 'BETA', 'GAMMA'): 5
    ('BETA', 'GAMMA', 'ALPHA'): 7
    ('BETA', 'GAMMA', 'ALPHA'): 1
    ('GAMMA', 'ALPHA', 'BETA'): 3}
```

This gives `ALPHA = 5, BETA = 8, GAMMA = 3`; this is what I really need in terms of a dictionary.

I tried to remove the least element and it's not working?

```
for (p, v) in my_dict.items():
        if (max(my_dict.values()) / sum(my_dict.values()):
            if (v == min(my_dict.values())):
                del my_dict[p]
        return my_dict
```

But this gives `ALPHA = 5, BETA = 7, GAMMA = 3`

Since this return a dictionary, how do I remove the duplicates with a `tuple` and return it back as a dictionary without *importing* anything?

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569105/how-to-properly-eliminate-elements-in-dictionary-until-one-string-remains/13569432).

Comment: The "return" statements in your pastes are misindented: they are inside the "for" loops.

Comment: My mistake, indentation typo while copying & pasting my code

Comment: Your second code block doesn't run, and if I fix the syntax errors doesn't give the answers you say.  Its also not clear how you get to each set of results, e.g. why do you expect `BETA=8`? Are the values in the dict changing?  And how are they changing?  Please post a full working example which we can run, along with the expected output.

Comment: I expected 'BETA=8' because I wanted to tally up the first indices of the tuples with the values. Instead of directly removing the least element from the dictionary, I want to know how to remove the least element by creating a new tuple. The idea is that I want to implement "Condorcet Voting". Which is similar to [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569105/how-to-properly-eliminate-elements-in-dictionary-until-one-string-remains/13569432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a suggestion ..
if we use your function:

```
def rad_type(particle):

   my_dict = {}

   for (k, v) in particle.items():
        if (k[0] in my_dict):
            my_dict[k[0]] += v
        else:
            my_dict[k[0]] = v

   return my_dict
```

and if we define another function that uses your function :

```
def filter(dict):
        filter1 = rad_type(dict)
        i = 0
        for k ,val in dict.items():
              dict[k] = filter1[k[0]]
              i +=1
        mini_key = [k for k , val in filter1.items() if val == min([value for key ,  value in filter1.items()])][0] 
        filter2 = {tuple(y for y in key if y != mini_key):value for key, value in dict.items()}
        filter3 = rad_type(filter2)
        return filter3
```

if we apply this function on the dictionary particle :

```
result = filter(particle)
```

the output is :

```
{'ALPHA': 5, 'BETA': 8, 'GAMMA': 3}
```

Comment: Is there a way without using 'filter'?

Comment: here filter is just a name , you can replace it in any other name (like helper for example) , you can try to copy the code and then replace every filter with helper and it will give the same output

Answer (score 0):

You're **going to need** a `Counter` of some kind.  I have implemented a solution using `Collections.Counter`, but if you can't import Counter directly, you have to implement it yourself.  Alternatively, `Collections.Counter` is pure python, you could just copy the source code of `Counter` to your own solution to avoid having to import it.

```
def display_results(data):
    ''' Displays the sum of the first entries in a tuple in a given dictionary

    >>> display_results(data)
    ... {'ALPHA': 5, 'BETA': 7, 'GAMMA': 3, 'DELTA': 1}'''

    data = Counter(data)
    count = Counter()
    for i in data:
        count[i[0]] += data[i]
    return count

def process_data(data):
    ''' Generates a new Counter object with the contents of data, minus the least common
    object in the first tuple as defined by display_results().

    >>> data = process_data(data)
    >>> display_results(data)
    {'ALPHA' : 5, 'BETA' : 7, 'GAMMA' : 3} '''

    data = Counter(data)
    count = Counter()
    least_common = display_results(data).most_common()[-1][0]
    for i in data:
        j = list(i)
        j.remove(least_common)
        count[tuple(j)] += data[i]
    return count
```